# Native swift zip decompression

Tags: swift, zip, compression

I would like to implement zip decompression without using external frameworks. I think that Compression framework from iOS SDK should be ok for this, but I'm not sure. I was looking for some examples on how to extract files using this but found nothing. I wan't to extract all files from zip to some directory (not Data object). Can someone help me starting this? Maybe some tutorials I haven't found? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/148569/unsafe-swift. In the end they end up wrapping the old C API for compressing and decompressing. Maybe you can find some clues in there.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read and see if I can use it. Still looks like they are decompressing only to Data, but maybe I'll find out how to convert this to directories.

Answer (score 2):

zlib, which is already there, provides the raw decompression and CRC calculation engines. From there you can write your own code to interpret the zip file structure, which is documented in the [PKWare appnote](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). It is relatively straightforward.